# Python, connecting vertical lists

Tags: python, string, list

I have this for example this characters:

```
.....U......
L...L.######
.S....#.....
....L.......
```

which i stored in a list

```
chars = ['.....U......', 'L...L.######', '.S....#.....', '....L.......']
```

I used this to store it in the chars:

```
for x in range(0, N):
    g = input()
    chars.append(g)
```

Now the problem is i want to turn all of the dots between letters L into # but vertically, so like this:

```
.....U......
L...L.######
.S..#.#.....
....L.......
```

I have been trying for a few hours now and i can't think of anything. Help much appreciated.

EDIT:
I used this to connect them horizontally. And it works.

```
while y != N:
    modchars0 = list(chars[y])

    if modchars0.count('L') == 0:
        y += 1

    else:
        for k in range(0, M):
            if 'L' in modchars0[k]:
                start = k + 1
                break

        for l in range(M-1, 0, -1):
            if 'L' in modchars0[l]:
                end = l
                break

        for h in range(start, end):
            if 'L' in modchars0[h]:
                pass
            else:
                modchars0[h] = '#'

        modchars1 = modchars1.join(modchars0)
        chars[y] = modchars1
        y += 1
```

Comment: `zip(*chars)` takes the transpose of `chars`. If you've already got a routine that works horizontally, you're set.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As @U2EF1 mentioned in comments you can take the transpose of the list using `zip(*chars)` and then using regex you can convert dots between 'L' to '#'. And then in the end `zip(*)` the new items again to get desired output:

```
>>> import re                                                             
>>> r = re.compile(r'(?<=L).*(?=L)')                     
>>> def rep(m):                                           
    return m.group().replace('.', '#')
... 
>>> zipped = (r.sub(rep, ''.join(x)) for x in zip(*chars))
>>> for x in zip(*zipped):
    print ''.join(x)
...     
.....U......
L...L.######
.S..#.#.....
....L.......
```

Comment: Isn't zipping and rezipping a bit overkill? Does this beat a simpler solution with longer lists, or with lists of longer strings? Not meant as a critic, I'm actually interested in learning.

Comment: @Roberto Computationally beyond overkill, yes. But this seemed primarily educational so it's not that bad.

Comment: @Roberto I didn't assume that OP wants to replace just `L.L` with `L#L`, my solution also works for cases like `L.SL`, `L....L`(OP said: *i want to turn all of the dots between letters L into #*). So, I don't think this is an overkill. If all they wanted is to turn `L.L` to `L#L` then surely this can be done in a better way.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary is correct. The characters don't have to even be the exact same width and height, so you could get L..L..L etc

Comment: Also in case annyone is wondering about the point of this, I'm planning to implement the a* algorithm to find the best way from U to S, #-cant go across these

Comment: @simon101 Hmm I'm deleting my answer then, as it is doesn't fit the specs. :)

Comment: Hmmm implementing a* seems harder than i thought, would someone tell me just what approach i should use to make the interaction with the list...

Answer (score 3):

**Late Answer**

This one probably doesn't deserve best answer, but is an alternative nevertheless.

First define a function that will rotate the list from horizontal to vertical:

```
def invert(chars):
    inverted = []
    for i in range(len(chars[0])):
        newStr=""
        for j in range(len(chars)):
            newStr+=chars[j][i]
        inverted.append(newStr)
    return inverted
```

Then you may use it in this manner:

```
def main():
    chars = ['.....U......', 'L...L.######', '.S....#.....', '....L.......']
    invChars = invert(chars)

    for i in range(len(invChars)):
        invChars[i] = re.sub(r'(?<=L)(\..*?)L', lambda k: k.group().replace('.','#'), invChars[i])

    chars = invert(invChars)
```

Comment: Your `invert` function can be done more simply and more efficiently (by avoiding reallocating strings every time around a loop) as `[''.join(c) for c in zip(*chars)]`.

Comment: I don't know about the output, but there's a clear syntax error in your code. So, better run it before posting.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary works now... I indented too many times in my invert function

Comment: Note that apart from [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28016327/python-connecting-vertical-lists/28016532?noredirect=1#comment44420865_28016424) your solution will also miss the overlapping groups: `L.L.L`

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary My original answer was intended to work for the example provided, but I edited nevertheless. Kindly let me know if I am missing something in my regex matching.